# HTML mapping dead space

Tags: android, html, dictionary, coordinates

I am making an html map for an android tablet for a museum exhibit. We used a picture of the exhibit for the basis of our map, and rectangle coordinates for the objects. When you click an object, you get brought to a page with more info about that object.

HOWEVER, when you click on a part of the map that has no defined coordinates, it says the webpage is not found. I want to make it so that the only responding parts of the map are the objects with defined coordinates.

How do I make it so that the dead space in the map is un-clickable and/or will not navigate away from the main page? HELP!

Comment: Showing HOW you built it would really help people answer this question.

Comment: You need to show your code, we cannot guess what you have written.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a client side image map, you can set a default value like this...

```
<map name="mymap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="91,30 186,98" href="/hit-the-box/" alt="the box">
  <area shape="default" href="/default/url/">
</map>
```